# Convert C# code to java

Tags: c#, java

I try to convert c# code to java,there is a one line i couldnt convert.

Here is the line :

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => runPlannedTestSets.findAndRunTestSet(waitingTestSet, availableHost)));
```

Comment: What research have you done into how you start a thread in Java? (Hint: substitute `Runnable` for `ThreadStart`, and use an anonymous inner class instead of a lambda expression, and you're nearly there...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today's Java 7 *doesn't support labmdas* as C# does, so you should transform your `() => ...`
into something like that (*local class*):

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    runPlannedTestSets.findAndRunTestSet(waitingTestSet, availableHost));
  } 
}

thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

runPlannedTestSets should implement runnable and findAndRunTestSet either could be the run method (rename) or the run method could call finAndRunTestSet.

The code will be:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(runPlannedTestSets);
```

then

```
thread.start();
```